# Mapping and replacing by a list of values Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes: `df1` is the ID table. I would like to use it to adjust the `Item_Id` in `df2`. I want to do this: where `Item_Id` in `df2` equals the numerical value in `Name` in `df1`, replace `Item_Id` with the corresponding `Id` in `df1`.

`df1`:

```
Id  Name
2   Item 002
3   Item 003
4   Item 004
5   Item 006
6   Item 007
7   Item 008
8   Item 009
9   Item 010
    ...
```

`df2`:

```
        Id      Timestamp               value   Item_Id Date    
2371    2412    2017-12-15 16:05:50.653 27.0    2       2017-12-15   
2373    2414    2017-12-15 16:05:50.653 25.0    3       2017-12-15
2375    2416    2017-12-15 16:05:50.653 42.0    4       2017-12-15  
2377    2418    2017-12-15 16:05:50.653 25.0    7       2017-12-15  
2379    2420    2017-12-15 16:05:50.653 25.0    10      2017-12-15
```

Expected output:

```
        Id      Timestamp               value   Item_Id Date    
2371    2412    2017-12-15 16:05:50.653 27.0    2       2017-12-15   
2373    2414    2017-12-15 16:05:50.653 25.0    3       2017-12-15
2375    2416    2017-12-15 16:05:50.653 42.0    4       2017-12-15  
2377    2418    2017-12-15 16:05:50.653 25.0    6       2017-12-15  
2379    2420    2017-12-15 16:05:50.653 25.0    9       2017-12-15
```

Comment: maybe I'm missing something here but how is df1 and df2 related. How would you combine them to get the expected output?

Comment: @sachinruk For instance, for the last line in df2, Item_Id  is 10, which is mapped to Item 010 in df1, where the Id is 9, thus 10 is replaced by 9 in Item_Id in the Expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use `pandas.Series.str.extract` and `map`:

```
s = df["Name"].str.extract("(\d+)", expand=False).astype(int)
mapper = df.set_index(s)["Id"].to_dict()
df2["Item_Id"] = df2["Item_Id"].map(mapper)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
        Id                Timestamp  value  Item_Id        Date
2371  2412  2017-12-15 16:05:50.653   27.0        2  2017-12-15
2373  2414  2017-12-15 16:05:50.653   25.0        3  2017-12-15
2375  2416  2017-12-15 16:05:50.653   42.0        4  2017-12-15
2377  2418  2017-12-15 16:05:50.653   25.0        6  2017-12-15
2379  2420  2017-12-15 16:05:50.653   25.0        9  2017-12-15
```

Answer (score 1):

Going by your comment above try this:

```py
# convert the string to a number
df1['Id2'] = df1['Name'].map(lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]))
# set this column as index so you can 'join'
df1.set_index('Id2', inplace=True)
# overwrite `Item_Id`
df2['Item_Id'] = df1.loc[df2['Item_Id'], 'Id']
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer, it returned `KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'`